# In C++ return -1 does not return any error?

Tags: c++, mingw

Should the super simple code below produce an error? Should it produce anything?

```
int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

I am just starting to work through the 'C++ Primer' and supposedly from Exercise 1.2:

> A return value of -1 is often treated as an indicator that the program failed. Recompile and rerun your program to see how your system treats a failure indicator from main.

It seems like my system treats a failure indicator as business as usual and it is driving me crazy!!!

I can return any number, positive or negative and there won't be an error. Only when I type in a string like 'return cisstupid;' I would (obviously) get an error. An hour of googling has not yielded anything and I have tried running the code with -Wpedantic, -Wall, -Werror (i.e. g++ -Wpedantic -o test test.cpp). The system is Windows 8.1 with mingw installed.

Comment: There's a difference between  '**is often** treated as an indicator that the program failed' and  '**must always** be treated as an indicator that the program failed'. Additionally, 'is often treated' doesn't imply it's the OS who treats (-1) as a failure indicator; it's usually a calling proces that tests the calee return status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs can complete with an error.  I'm not sure what kind of shell you are using, but with a bash shell, you can type `echo $?` to get the return code of the last executed program.

To understand why this is, consider this: Most of the time, you do not want the entire system to come to a halt.  You do, however, want to know that something went wrong.  So it is common to call something, get the return value, then react appropriately, rather than let the entire thing blow up.

Comment: I'm using the command line in Windows and echo %errorlevel% just returns 0 :/

Comment: @user45797: you're doing something wrong, but I don't know what.  `echo %errorlevel%` returns the value returned from the last program run (-1 in the case where I run your simple test program).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm not sure what is wrong either, I've installed mingw from http://www.mingw.org/ and when I tried the program with `return 0, 1, or -1`; followed by `echo %errorlevel%`, all of them return 0. When I intentionally generate the error with `return cisstupid;`, `echo %errorlevel%` returns 1. Is there some setting I'm missing with mingw?

Comment: Um - are you executing the `echo %errorlevel%` command after only compiling your program?  In that case, you're getting the return value from the compiler (essentially whether or not the compile step was successful).  If you want the return value from *your* program, then you have to run it after you compile it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Fantastic, that was what I was doing wrong! Thanks for figuring out my newbie mistake! Now I can stop letting this bother me and go get some sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

`return` keyword is used to return some value to the calling function by the function that has been called this return value can be almost anything the interpretation of the return value entirely depends on how the calling function has handled the return value.

```
int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

Here you are simply returning a negative number using return whose interpretation can be handled in the calling function (here Operatin.
This is a convention not a protocol or rule to treat this return value as an operational error for the program , depending on the calling system the value of return can effect the output ie. as  CiaPan  stated that there is much difference between the *often* and *always* words.

*In Short the interpretation of `return -1` depends on the calling System.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, yes, returning anything is business as always. I'm not sure about other systems, but I've never heard of using a different return value in main to indicate something bad has happened to the user.

The actual use for return values is just as you know them, to get information back. The return value of main is used the same way. If you're in A.exe and call B.exe, then you can use main's return value to indicate whether or not B.exe ran successfully. However, where you're at now, you'll never do that, hence you just always `return 0`.

Comment: With the way the exercise is worded, I was just expecting something to happen so I would get to see what happens when a program 'fails'. I guess I'll just move on to the next exercise then :)

Comment: Yep, don't blame you. Rather poor wording.